# how can i set ion-select value a number with reactive form using form group?

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
<ion-select formControlName="FollowUpType"
          (ngModelChange)="reset()">
          <ion-option value="0">
            A
          </ion-option>
          <ion-option value="1">
           B
          </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

I need this select when I take it's value to be number not string (0 number , or 1 number ) not "0" and not "1".
I'm using reactive form  :

```
 this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
      FollowUpType: [''],
   });
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? 0 as in the `value="0"` or 0 which you have used between `<ion-option>0</ion-option>`?

Comment: No, I mean when I want to get the value from ion-select I want it to be number not string : I mean FollowUpType in the formBuilder to be number so I can sent it to the server with type number. I know I can setValue(ParseInt(value)) but i want another solution because something now work

Comment: Can you use indexes? As index will be the number part only.

Comment: i'm not using ngFor to use index

Comment: how about `FollowUpType: [parseInt('')],`?

Comment: how about trying `<ion-option [value]="0">`?

Answer (score 10):

You should bind as `[value]` and not `value`

```
<ion-select formControlName="FollowUpType" (ngModelChange)="reset()">
    <ion-option [value]="0">A</ion-option>
    <ion-option [value]="1">B</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 8):

What I see here are a couple of options, which both tho requires work, other for styling, other for extra variables. So going for `parseInt()` before passing the data to the backend would be preferable.

Option one is to just use `select` instead of `ion-select`, with that, `ngValue` works, which can capture the number. But that requires styling for the select to look like an ionic select.

Option two would be to have two variables and use `[value]` in the select instead of `select`.

Final option would then be to use an array

```
values = [{value:0, label:'A'},{value:1, label: 'B'}]
```

iterate it and use it together with `[value]`:

```
<ion-select formControlName="FollowUpType" (ionChange)="reset()">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let val of values" [value]="val.value">
     {{val.label}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Demo with all three: http://plnkr.co/edit/dwbttQZTh9JGwKcvFtTX?p=preview

Maybe easiest is to just go with `parseInt()` for the value before sending it to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

This info might help someone:

You need to set the formControlName in the ion-select, not in the ion-item, if you're using the select inside an item.

It seems that ion-select doesn't refresh the values if formControlName is set in ion-item. The same goes for ion-datetime.